# Remove users from a Skype group

Tags: skype

I executed the `/kick fistname lastname` `/kick [firstname lastname]` command in the group I created, but they didn't apply. There is no right-click option as there is on the Windows Skype version to remove a user from a group. Many other commands doesn't seem to work as well.

Skype version: 4.3.0.37

Comment: Possibly someone here can help, but otherwise I think that the [Skype Community](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/bd-p/Linux) is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use skype login name instead of [firstname lastname]:

```
/kick <login>
```

Comment: Yes, I found out that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about "/kick" It's 06/2020 and I've been unable to find such an option. Now you just enter the group chat, below its name there is number of participants -> click on that number -> now you just hover your mouse on the user you want to remove and click "Remove" button which appears to the left from the user.

!!! IMPORTANT MOMENT. You need to be admin of the group !!!

There are 2 roles available: Admin and User. To figure it out, in group chat enter:

```
/showmembers
```

You'll see who's admin, who's user and who are YOU. In case if you're not admin ask admin user to share Admin permissions with you with a command line inside of the groupchat:

```
/setrole $yourskypeid Admin
```

Now you can remove users.